# Set up Flutter project in Android Studio with multiple local packages outside of root folder

Tags: android, flutter, macos, android-studio

I have a Flutter project like this ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9QMi.png) is a more complete screenshot of the file tree):

```
Folder:
   project.main
      lib
         main.dart
   local flutter package 1
   local flutter package 2
   ...
```

All of the local packages are referenced in `pubspec.yaml` in the `project.main` folder

I'm trying to find a way to open the whole project so I can launch the main.dart and view and edit the code form the other local packages as well.

---

If I only open the projects.main folder, the project gets detected as a Flutter project, but I haven't found a way to import and view the local packages.

If I open the folder containing the main folder and all the packages, I can get it to run after specifying the dart .sdk path, which is kind of strange. But I am missing features like the Flutter inspector then.

My question is: is there a way to set up this kind of project in Android Studio, such that all of these features will work correctly?